# How to delete newly generated files in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete the files whichever is newly created in that path.

In our case, we will have multiple files in a certain path. After running our application, it will create new files. I need to delete these new files alone.

Initially we thought of making all the existing files as Read-Only. So deleting file `*.*` will delete only the new files. But that option is ruled out, in our project we cannot make the files as read-only.

So I am trying to find an other way to delete these new files.

Comment: How many files do you need to delete at once?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes the application will create 10 new files, so in this case, we need to delete these 10 files. Sometimes it will create 15 files, so this case we need to delete these 15 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more or less what you require:

```
@echo off
set newfile=
set oldfile=
:start
for /f %%i in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d /o-d') do set "newfile=%%i" & goto reveal
:reveal
if not defined oldfile set "oldfile=%newfile%"
if not "%newfile%"=="%oldfile%" (
    echo deleting %newfile%
    del %newfile% /Q
    set oldfile=
)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak>nul 2>&1
goto start
```

It will run in a permanent loop and every three seconds wil lit recheck the directory for new `.txt` files. Once detected, it will echo `deleting file.txt` and delete the file.

obviously you can increase the `timeout` value if needed.

To test this, place it in any directory and run the script. open explorer and browse to the directory and create a a new file `test.txt` and see how it disappears.

**Edit** Based on the requirement to delete multple files:

create one batch file which will do the file listings, you need to update the paths of the directories in the demo paths below.. Then run this script once off which will create the `exclusion.txt` file in the `%temp%` dir.

```
@echo off
dir /b "C:\directory">"%temp%\exclusion.txt"
dir /b "C:\directory 2">>"%temp%\exclusion.txt"
dir /b "D:\directory 3">>"%temp%\exclusion.txt"
```

Now copy this file into each of the directories you want to delete stuff from:

```
@echo off
set cnt=0 & set excl= & set ext=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%temp%\exclusion.txt") do (
    set /a cnt+=1   
    set "nlr!cnt!=%%a"
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    if not defined excl (
         set "excl=!nlr%%i!"
    ) else (
         set "excl=!excl! !nlr%%i!"
   )
)
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /VIE "%excl%"') do (
     if /i not "%%i"=="exclusion.txt" if not "%%i"=="%~0" echo del "%%i"
)
```

So what will now happen is, it will delete all the files in the directory, unless it is in the `exclusion.txt`

For now, this solution will only `echo` the del command, once you are happy it will delete only what is intended to be deleted, you need to remove `echo` from the second last line.

Lastly, if you ever need to add new files to the directories that should not be deleted, just rerun your `dir` batch file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my case, I am going to run the batch file only after the new files are generated. (which means after our application run completed which creates these new files, I am going to run the batch file). Also there will be lot of files in that path. Moreover we are going to do the same operation in multiple places (multiple paths). So each path will have its own file names which will be different. Also the new generated files will have dynamic name. So is there anyway we can delete files using time stamp or similar approach?

Comment: ok, but you would need to be more pecific, how often do you start the application?

Comment: Currently we are having a batch file which will run our application. For eg.) Runtest.bat. So this will run our application and generate the new files. So next time before I run this batch file again, I need to run our new batch file which should delete all the newly generated files.

Comment: Well, we can just use the method in the previous answer.. We list all the current files once off to a exclusion file, then it will only delete new files.

Comment: ya maybe that's the only way. What I thought is, in the same way we have around 100 different directories. All these paths will have unique file name. So all this path, should have its own exclusion lists. Instead I thought, whether we could do something in common.

Comment: but that is not difficult to do. we can simply do `dir /b /a-d "D:\directory\">exclusion.txt && dir /b /a-d "D:\directory2\">>exclusion.txt` this way you list all the files in the directory, when you then run the script, all these files will be excluded. You just need to then copy the script into all the folders, add the `exclusion.txt` file to a specific folder and point to it.

Comment: See the edit in the answer... Just so you know, we can delete by date/time, but that is dangerous because if other files are modified, it will also change the date/time.. so this is possibly the best solution.

Comment: perfect. Thank you

Comment: Oh and please recopy dir commands above, I fogot to append >>

Comment: and before you actually run any of these delete commands, BACKUP your files!!